# Recalculate raster

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I'm trying to use the QGIS recalculate raster function. I have a raster with values from -47.xxx to 57.xxx. it also has areas of nodata.

I have found instructions on how to implement the boolean mask and recalculate ->
"("Nabak Slope Risk@1" >0)*"Nabak Slope Risk@1"/57.517082*100"
This gives max value of 99.999 (as expected) and -340,282,346,638,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx as the minimum value.

How can I set this minimum value to 0.
rerunning the raster calculator with (a<0)*0 and similar produces the same min value result.

Comment: That math seems off,  -47.0/57.517082100 = -0.8171485458578226 not what appears to be the minimum float value... what is the NoData value of your Nabak Slope Risk? It sounds to me like the NoData value of the dataset isn't defined properly. If not you can do a further calculation trimming off values outside the expected range (say -1 to 100 should be good enough).

Comment: Thanks - am starting to believe your reference to the nodata value is correct. Will look up how to section off the required range of pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is indeed the 'nodata' value - the actual value is presumably dependent on the data type.